# Probability approach to divisibility of numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two numbers $x$ and $y$ are chosen at random from the set $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots, 3n\}$. Find the probability that $x^2-y^2$ is divisible by $3$.

I followed following approach $(x-y)(x+y) = 3k$.

It is only when two numbers whose difference is multiple of $3$ is selected viz. $(1,4),(1,7), \ldots, (1,1000)$ etc. or two number whose sum is multiple of $3$ is selected like $(1,2),(1,5)$ etc. From this step, I am not able to proceed as we have case where both are possible e.g $(3,6)$ whose difference and sum is multiple of $3$.

Comment: how many possible values are there of x^2-y^2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $x^2-y^2$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if one of the following holds:

- both $x$ and $y$ are multiples of $3$;
- neither $x$ nor $y$ is a multiple of $3$.

Can you work out the probabilities of each of these options separately?